# Objective-C calling method from super object.

Tags: objective-c, methods

I have an object called "Object B", that is spawned by "Object A". Is it possible for Object B to call a method in Object A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object B must have a property that Object A can set.

Like this:

```
@interface B {
  A *a;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) A *a; // synthesize this
@end
```

In A:

```
B *b = [[B alloc] init];
b.a = self;
```

Then, b can just send messages to a.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you when *spawning* "Object B" also pass it a reference to "Object A". For example:

```
ObjectB* b = [[ObjectB alloc] initWithObjectA:self];
```